# Synchronize two ListView positions

Tags: android

I have two ListViews. Is there any way to synchronize the position of ListViews when I scroll any one of the  Lists

Answer (score 2):

Implement an [AbsListView.OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html), register to the ListView. When the ListView is scrolled, the onScroll() method of OnScrollListener will be triggered, then call [smoothScrollToPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) on another ListView to synchronize to the same position.

Comment: You need a way to avoid the second listView to issue onScrolled when you call smoothScrollToPosition.

Answer (score 1):

We did this and it worked well for us.

```
listOne.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
       listTwo.dispatchTouchEvent(arg1);
       return false;
    }
});
listOne.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
   }
   @Override
   public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
          if (l1.getChildAt(0) != null) {
              Rect r = new Rect();
              l1.getChildVisibleRect(l1.getChildAt(0), r, null);
              l2.setSelectionFromTop(l1.getFirstVisiblePosition(), r.top);
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is nearly there, but I'm finding `r.top` is always zero.